# How to manage properly south migrations for a reusable app using django-modeltranslation?

Tags: python, django, localization, django-south, django-modeltranslation

I have a reusable application. In this app, some models need to be localized and I am using the django-modeltranslation app for it.

Using django-modeltranslation cause the south migrations to include the localized field in the model defintion.

For example, I i have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

And the following translation.py file

```
class MyModelOptions(TranslationOptions):
   fields = ('name',)

translator.register(MyModel, MyModelOptions)
```

and two languages, fr and en, defined in my settings.py

If I run a south schemamigration on this app, south will add the `name_fr` and `name_en` field to the model definition of the migration

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
         #Here the columns are created depending but It can be managed for all languages in settings.LANGUAGES
         for (lang, _x) in settings.LANGUAGES:
             #create the column for the language


def backwards(self, orm):
         #Simimar workaround than forwards can be implemented

models = {
    'myapp.mymodel': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'MyModel'},
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100'}),

        #The following items are the model definition and can not be generated from settings.LANGUAGES
        'name_en': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
        'name_fr': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
    }
```

As far as I know, this model definition is generated by south in a hard coded way.

As a consequence, it is difficult to maintain the south migrations for a reusable app using django-modeltranslation because there is no way to know in advance what are the languages defined in the settings.py of the project.

What would you recommend to manage this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option I choosed is to disable (remove from INSTALLED_APPS ) `models translation` when making a `schemamigration` and let `sync_translation_fields` manage the creation of missing translation fields.

It seems an acceptable method : https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/106#issuecomment-33875679

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I wouldn't add those migrations to the package at all, one shouldn't force fixtures upon a 3rd party user. A nice way could be to create a demo project within the package and add proper documentation, e.g. (django 1.4+)

```
repository_root/
    example/
        example/
            __init__.py
            urls.py
            settings.py
            static/
                js/
            fixtures/
                data.json
            migrations/
                reusable_app/
                    __init__.py
                    0001_initial.py
        manage.py
    reusable_app/
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        admin.py
```

Add a few settings to settings.py to keep things clean

```
def rel(*x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    rel('fixtures'),
)

SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'reusable_app': 'example.migrations.reusable_app',
}
```

Make sure you add the following line after your import statements in `manage.py` to make sure you're working on the local reusable_app not the (installed) one in site-packages

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```